# How to add RestSharp Response to API Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, restsharp

I've created an ASP.NET Core API solution that uses RestSharp to send data to a third party API and return results back to my API and database. On my API, I want to return the results of the RestSharp call as part of my controller class so that my DNN site can consume the RestSharp Responses.  How do I return the responses obtained from the third party API in my controller class?

My RestSharp logic is as follows:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Executes a particular http request to a resource.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The response type.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="request">The REST request.</param>
    /// <param name="baseUrl">The base URL.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns a response of the type parameter.</returns>
    private static T Execute<T>(IRestRequest request, string baseUrl) where T : class, new()
    {
        baseUrl = "https://xmltest.propay.com/api/propayapi/PropayMerchantService.svc/";
        var client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
        var response = client.Execute<T>(request);

        if (response.ErrorException != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "Error: Exception: {0}, Headers: {1}, Content: {2}, Status Code: {3}",
                response.ErrorException,
                response.Headers,
                response.Content,
                response.StatusCode);
        }

        return response.Data;
    } 
    public static ProPayResponse MerchantSignUpForProPay()
    {
        var baseUrl = "https://xmltest.propay.com/api/propayapi/PropayMerchantService.svc/";
        var request = BuildMerchantTestData();
        var restRequest = CreateRestRequest("/Signup", Method.PUT);
        restRequest.AddJsonBody(request);
        return Execute<ProPayResponse>(restRequest, baseUrl);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Builds the merchant request data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The request data.</returns>
    private static SignUpRequest BuildMerchantTestData()
    {

        var onboarding = new Onboarding();
        var signUpRequest = new SignUpRequest();
        var userid = "userId";
        var email = userid + "@test.com";

        using (SOBOContext context = new SOBOContext())
        {
            var signupRequest = new SignUpRequest
            {
                SignupAccountData = new SignupAccountData
                {
                    ExternalId = "12345",
                    Tier = onboarding.AverageTicket.ToString(),
                    CurrencyCode = "USD",
                    PhonePIN = onboarding.PhonePin,
                    UserId = onboarding.UserName
                },
                Address =
                                            new Address
                                            {
                                                Address1 = onboarding.Address1Line1,
                                                Address2 = onboarding.Address1Line1,
                                                ApartmentNumber = " ",
                                                City = onboarding.Address1City,
                                                State = onboarding.Address1State,
                                                Country = onboarding.Address1Country,
                                                Zip = onboarding.Address1ZipCode
                                            },
                BusinessAddress =
                                            new Address
                                            {
                                                Address1 = onboarding.BusinessAddressLine1,
                                                Address2 = onboarding.BusinessAddressLine2,
                                                ApartmentNumber = " ",
                                                City = onboarding.BusinessCity,
                                                State = onboarding.BusinessState,
                                                Country = onboarding.BusinessCountry,
                                                Zip = onboarding.BusinessZipCode
                                            },
                MailAddress = new Address { Address1 = onboarding.OwnerAddress, City = onboarding.OwnerCity, State = onboarding.OwnerRegion, Country = onboarding.OwnerCountry, Zip = onboarding.OwnerZipCode },
                BankAccount =
                                            new BankAccount
                                            {
                                                AccountCountryCode = onboarding.BankAccount1CountryCode,
                                                AccountType = onboarding.BankAccount1Type,
                                                AccountOwnershipType = onboarding.BankAccount1OwnershipType,
                                                BankAccountNumber = onboarding.BankAccount1Number,
                                                BankName = onboarding.BankAccount1BankName,
                                                RoutingNumber = onboarding.BankAccount1RoutingNumber
                                            },
                SecondaryBankAccount =
                                            new BankAccount
                                            {
                                                AccountCountryCode = onboarding.BankAccount2CountryCode,
                                                AccountType = onboarding.BankAccount2Type,
                                                AccountOwnershipType = onboarding.BankAccount2OwnershipType,
                                                BankAccountNumber = onboarding.BankAccount2Number,
                                                BankName = onboarding.BankAccount2BankName,
                                                RoutingNumber = onboarding.BankAccount2RoutingNumber
                                            },
                BusinessData =
                                            new BusinessData
                                            {
                                                BusinessLegalName = onboarding.BusinessLegalName,
                                                DoingBusinessAs = onboarding.DoingBusinessAs,
                                                EIN = onboarding.Ein,
                                            },
                CreditCardData = new CreditCardData
                {
                    CreditCardNumber = onboarding.CreditCardNumber, // test card number
                    ExpirationDate = onboarding.ExpirationDate
                },
                PersonalData =
                                            new PersonalData
                                            {
                                                DateOfBirth = onboarding.DateOfBirth.ToString(),
                                                SourceEmail = onboarding.Email,
                                                SocialSecurityNumber = onboarding.Ssn,
                                                FirstName = onboarding.FirstName,
                                                LastName = onboarding.Lastname,
                                                MiddleInitial = onboarding.MiddleInitial,
                                                PhoneInformation =
                                                        new PhoneInformation { DayPhone = onboarding.DayPhone, EveningPhone = onboarding.EveningPhone }
                                            }
            };
            context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return signupRequest;
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Request factory to ensure API key is always first parameter added.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="resource">The resource name.</param>
    /// <param name="method">The HTTP method.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns a new <see cref="RestRequest"/>.</returns>
    private static RestRequest CreateRestRequest(string resource, Method method)
    {

        var credentials = GetCredentials();

        var restRequest = new RestRequest { Resource = resource, Method = method, RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json, };
        restRequest.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
        restRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", credentials);
        return restRequest;
    }
```

My controller class thus far is as follows:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetMerchantSignUp()
    {

            await _context.ProPayResponse.ToListAsync();
            return Ok();
    }
```

Are there any other steps needed to retrieve the RestSharp responses and expose them in my controller class?

Comment: I'm not sure where to start so I guess I'll ask what do you think is missing or that you're doing in a non-elegant fashin?

Comment: I'm thinking that the API Controller needs to show a list of entries from the SignupResponse class.  This list can then be consumed by a web control so that the end user knows the responses received to the various onboarding requests.  Not sure what to return in my controller class e.g. the RestSharp response or the model class contents?

Comment: This is probably a preference regarding your system. If a 3rd party was going to call this API I would absolutely not expect to receive a RestSharp response but rather whatever I called the API for